# Memory Leaks using Executors.newFixedThreadPool()

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jakarta-ee, jms

I am using Spring3.1 on a standalone env.

(this problem not necessary related to Spring. it's behaving the same also on a standalone env.)

I have implements a listener which receives messages from Topic. the messages rate is very very high (talking about 20/30 m/s).

some messages can take more processing time then other.

The listener works with the same instance which means that if one message being processed too long it hits our performances pretty much.

We thought about doing our own pool of objects instead of using the same listener instance but then I found out the **Executors**(java.util.concurrent.Executors).

So for each message received a different thread will be allocated to it. this will make sure our listener instance will be free to process messages parallel.

```
private ExecutorService  threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message msg)
    {
        Runnable t = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                onSessionMessage(msg);
                log.trace("AbstractSessionBean, received messge");
            }
        };
        threadPool.execute(t);
    }
```

That seems to solve our performance issue. but after monitoring the application with jconsole we facing now huge memory leaks.

The heap memory usage being increased significantly in time.

So I tried to "play" a bit with the FixedThreadPool size number. still having huge memory usage:

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this? any other ideas to solve my key problem?

[image: jconsole after performing GB]

[image: jconsole overall view]

After running heap dump I got two problem suspects:

[image: Head Dump]

thanks,
ray.

Comment: What happens over time? Does the memory get reclaimed or are you facing OOM?

Comment: Hi Andrew actually I didn't test my program that far.. because it seems like the OOM is coming up..

Comment: Also, if you're already profiling: Can you make a heapdump to see what objects are really consuming the space?

Comment: @Thomas this param could be taken from jconsole? or Do I need a specific tool for that?

Comment: @rayman You can use visualvm for taking a heap dump

Comment: `jmap` can do this, just search on the internet. A good profiler will have the option to take a live snapshot or inspect heap at runtime.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, I used jmap in the remote server where I am running my app. it has created huge file. how could I analyze it?

Comment: I tried to analyze the file with MAT and I get error: Parser found 0 HPROF dumps in file FIX_jmap_heap_dump1.txt. No heap dump index 0 found. See FAQ. any idea?

Comment: I have fixed that error. anyway How should I pass the heap file details over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have no problem with memory leak, I cannot see it from your jconsole chart at least. There is no major GC collection. So it seems only more and more objet allocated into tenured(old) generation. To ensure about memory leak you should Perform GC and after that compare allocated memory. If you find a leak you are able to make a heap dump with jmap or visual tool(standart JDK tools). After this heap dump can be analyzed with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Before taking heap dump it is better to Perform GC to decrease heap dump file size.

Some notes:

- Threads count shouldn't affect heap memory explicitly. It maybe useful for you to review next [java memory structure](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sP7by9zlbVQ/TaZ5LIfRxdI/AAAAAAAAAmg/diXDFa64OTo/s1600/MemoryStructure.png). So thread require stack memory not a heap.
- In general it is not good idea to create cache for not heavy object, because of GC works algorithm.
- Also I think you should consider [cached thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) or calibrate ThreadPoolSize according server hardware.

Comment: you said "There is no major GC collection". how could I fix that? this is how I run my env: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 \

Comment: Accordingly your jconsole screenshot you have 1gb committed memory. But used only 30mb in average. In 3 hours your old memory growth up to 10mb. So JVM decide do not stop your application to collect old generation heap, because of a lot of memory is free. Initiate PerformGC to ensure no memory leaks exists in your application. Also if you decrease Xmx(it is recommended to set this value the same in Server application) for example to 50mb GC should be executed more often.

Comment: In JConsole Details exist part: GC time. It shows how much time app spent in GC. ParNew - is Eden space collection. ConcurrentMarkSweep means Tenured generation(major GC collection).

Comment: Wierd thing.. i am initiating PerformGC  via the jconsole. but nothing really happens.. (i am connecting from the jconsole remotely to the app vir RMI)

Comment: It would be great if you updated post with new screenshot of jconsole after performing GC.

Comment: I have also tried to parse the kjmap file with MAT and I got this: Parser found 0 HPROF dumps in file FIX_jmap_heap_dump1.txt. No heap dump index 0 found. See FAQ. any idea?

Comment: About heapDump: Do you set -dump:[live,]format=b,file=<filename> format "b" parameter when taking heap dump? I recommend to use jvisualvm to making heapdump.

Comment: About new screenshot: it is strange, but there wasn't major collection for your application after performing GC.

Comment: Ok. I got the heap dump.. but how should I pass it over here? it's huge

Comment: To analyze heapDump you should understand application Object topology deeply. Load heapDump into MAT and it propose for you most suspicious Object graphs. But nevertheless I doubt you has an memory leak in you application. Causes I described in first comment.

Comment: So how do you suggest the garbage to be collected? between after loading it to MAT It showed me two problem suspects I will update my post.

Comment: Sorry, I have a type in prev comment. I suppose you have no memory leak:) MAT shows general Object. First is ClassLoader's collection, second is standard Java caches. There no leaks. Also I think you cannot perform GC manually because of -XX:+DisableExplicitGC parameter in your Application. You should temporary remove this parameter. Also could you add Tenured generation and Eden generation chart form jConsole if you have?

Comment: Ok ill disable -XX:+DisableExplicitGC and re-perform what you asked.

Comment: Tenured generation and Eden generation? I see only charts: Heap memory usages, non heap memory usage, memory pool cms, memory pool par eden space, ..par surviver space, .. code cache, CMS PERM GEN to which ones you meant? i am creating new test

Comment: I meant Memory Pool "CMS Old Gen" and Par Eden space.

Comment: I i lost it.. but what should I do next.. I have no idea.. with all comments and stuff still couldnt find answer..

Comment: Think it is better to start monitoring again. I think you have no memory leaks in your application. You allocated enlarge memory for your application, so GC never start in two hours. And you cannot perform GC manually because of -XX:+DisableExplicitGC parameter. Remove parameter and start monitoring again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21309/discussion-between-rayman-and-taky)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue you encountered is the threadPool not releasing its resources. You need to call threadPool.shutdown() after you are finished submitting or executing. This will wait until the tasks have completed before terminating threads which can then be garbage collected.

From official Java api website:

"An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources." 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()

Alternatively you can use a newCachedThreadPool() which "Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available" see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

When I encountered this problem, I went with the newFixedThreadPool() and shutdown option.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but if you create 30 messages per second and it takes the computer (even in parallel) longer to process these 30 messages than 1 second, then youre queue of submitted tasks will grow uncontrollably. You should make sure no tasks are submitted if the queue size is larger than a set number and wait a bit. Each Message object uses memory and I think this could be your problem. A cachedthreadpool would not solve this.

You could quite simply test this by printing out youre queue size. Dont know if this was solved already....

Answer (score 0):

After the usage of ExecutorService, You need to stop the thread pool, as it is the same resource, like a file or a database or anything else that requires an explicit release. ExecutorService has methods shutdown() and shutdownNow() which can be used in a finally block to gargabe collect.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class SimpExec {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(5);
    CountDownLatch CountDownLatch2 = new CountDownLatch(5);

    ExecutorService eService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    eService.execute(new MyThread(countDownLatch, "A"));
    eService.execute(new MyThread(CountDownLatch2, "B"));


    try {
      countDownLatch.await();
      CountDownLatch2.await();

    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
      System.out.println(exc);
    }
      finally{

        eService.shutdown(); // This is the method we use to avoid memory Leaks.
        // eService.shutdownNow(); // -do-
       }
  }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
  String name;

  CountDownLatch latch;

  MyThread(CountDownLatch c, String n) {
    latch = c;
    name = n;
    new Thread(this);
  }

  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      latch.countDown();
    }
  }
}
```

If you forget to shutdown, the memory leak happens, It is also like streams that are not normally closed by JVM, because the default Executors does not create daemon threads.

Comment: If you didn't shutdown ThreadPool your application is not finish executing, is it?

Comment: no, execution will of course happen. But memory leaks can't be handled.

Comment: If you shutdown(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) ExecutorService it never perform task before recreation. Main idea of thread pool is to reuse thread to perform different task asynchronously.

Comment: threadPool.execute(t); which executes your thread service. and only after the execution we SHUTDOWN as I have shown in my code! So Shutdown() is the method which makes sure all your resources of ExecutorService are Garbage collected.

Comment: Sorry, but let's review javaDoc: Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. So all threads in thread poll will stop. How application will process others messages?

Comment: Accordingly your code you propose to shutdown ThreadPool after each processed message. If we processed message constantly(seems it is raymen's case) we should shutdown pool only after server shutdown requested. Also ThreadPool doesn't initiate HEAP memory leak, because of it manipulate Thread object that mostly use stack memory.

Comment: I find Taky right. I don't find any sense of shutting down the threadpool after each message received .

Comment: I was just trying to give you the example and it went wrong. All I mentioned from the beginning was to use the method when you are done with your executions.